# libGDX cone rotation while maintaing location in X,Y,Z

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx

I am trying to create some sort of "lighthouse" effect by creating a cone and rotating it around the X/Y. The result "runs off" on the Z axis and is also wrong on the Y/X axis if there is a combination of both a Yaw and Pitch degrees.[image]
(The Z axis goes from right to left, X towards the screen, Y upwards).
The yellow cone is the effect. it starts as the see-through cone.

This is hoe the x,y,z locations of the cone are set:

```
float c = this.height/2;
    this.locationX = player.getPosition().x - c*((float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(tiltOnY)));
    this.locationY = player.getPosition().y + c*((float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(tiltOnX)));
    this.locationZ = player.getPosition().z-c;
```

where height is the height of the cone, and tilt starts at 0 and is added or reduced (as a result of input) with module of 360 degrees.
This is the code in render:

```
inst = new ModelInstance(this._game_.viewConeModel);
    inst.transform.setToTranslation(cone.getX(),cone.getY(),cone.getZ())
    .rotate(Vector3.Y,cone.getTiltOnY()).rotate(Vector3.X,cone.getTiltOnX()).rotate(Vector3.X,90);

    this._game_.modelBatch.render(inst,this._game_.environment);
```

The desired result is that the point of the cone remains in the same location, but the cone itself rotates by the tilts on X and Y axis.

Comment: Have you tryed the other `rotate` or `setToRotation` versions?